# What credit card swiper will work with stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, pci-compliance

We built an ecommerce platform (like a Shopify) that allows our customers - the merchants to accept payments for products.

As of now, all payments are accepted online. When they sign up to use our service, they also sign up for stripe and we process payments through their hosted form for ease of PCI Compliance.

In a live setting, many of our customers want to use a swiper to accept payments for their products rather than typing in a credit card number on a tablet.

Do you have any suggestions for a third party swiper provider with an API that we can integrate?

Comment: This question isn't on-topic here - it's really hard to give a recommendation that can remain valid over time.  I can tell you from personal experience, though, that if you're going to be sending the data to Stripe, it needs to be [a device Stripe supports](https://stripe.com/works-with/category/card-readers-pos).  Any  swiper (other than one that's just a pure magstripe reader, which isn't PCI compliant) has to be supported by your processor - Stripe, in this case.

Comment: @Bobson thank you for your reply. The problem with many of those providers is that they are a separate third party service, much like us, with their own ecommerce tools, built on top of stripe. I’m looking for a solution for us to integrate directly. Do you know if any hardware providers?

Comment: [CardFlight](https://cardflight.com/cardflight-for-stripe/) on that page looks like it's just the reader and SDK.  The problem is that Stripe has to have support to decrypt the data from any reader that encrypts it.  So if they don't list it as supported, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe now offers its own set of supported EMV devices:

https://stripe.com/terminal

You can also use PayWorks or CardFlight (as of today) and can find those integrations here:

https://stripe.com/works-with/type/extension/category/card-readers

Lastly, if your'e just looking to use a magstripe reader, you should email into Support https://support.stripe.com/email for more guidance.

Comment: thanks for suggestion of stripe-terminal, which I am trying to implement, but could you help me for my custom-setup? I have explained it here in details, https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android/issues/78